# Approach towards designing an Application for Android Tablets?

Tags: android-layout, android

I am working on application which is currently for Phones only...but I need to make it for tablets as well. What should be my approach...??? Should I handle tablet resolution in the same application which is for Phones and let the same apk working for all phones and Tablets or I should make a separate project Tablet Specific..???

I am really confused at it..??? Please tell me what are the standard approaches, a separate app Tab Specific or as I mentioned earlier only one app handling Tabs, Phones etc. Suggestions and Recommendations are always welcomed... Thanks...!!!

Comment: You should organize your post into a list of **SPECIFIC** questions. This way it is a lot easier to read.

Comment: add a folder to your resources namely drawable-xhdpi, and add images and icons accordingely, eg spning board icon for tablet is of 96X96 px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through the following:

[Supporting Tablets and Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

There's no need to develop/design separate .apk files for Tabs and Phones. Just one .apk is enough to handle everything, unless the size of you .apk crosses 50MB. You can start reading about maintaining different/multiple apks from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html).

Hope this helps.